# How can I create a loop to search through an object for the correct value in java?

Tags: java, loops, object, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to search through an object to see if a user's input matches what the program has stored, but I cannot figure out a way to make it work. I attempted to see if the value inputed by a user matched that of one in the userID spot for any of these *Employee* objects, but that didn't work. For example, here is the object:

```
Employee{userID='u1234567', userSalary=65000, userType=true}
Employee{userID='u1938562', userSalary=100000, userType=true}
Employee{userID='u1047218', userSalary=125000, userType=false}
Employee{userID='u1530078', userSalary=55000, userType=true}
Employee{userID='u1088621', userSalary=78400, userType=true}
Employee{userID='u2405234', userSalary=105000, userType=false}
Employee{userID='u1142592', userSalary=87500, userType=true}
Employee{userID='u1000092', userSalary=235000, userType=true}
Employee{userID='u1220433', userSalary=450000, userType=false}
Employee{userID='u1082304', userSalary=95000, userType=true}
```

My first function attempts to match the user's input with one of the userID's, but like I said it only works with the "u1234567"'s line. I have been attempting this for quite a while now, but I am relatively new to java and so I'm still learning. Below is my code, and where I commented out the "This is where I'm trying to loop through objects to look for a match" is where I would think to place this code, but I would greatly appreciate any feedback or better suggestions.

```js
package homework4;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // pass the path to the file as a parameter
        Scanner file_in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        // CREATE NEW ARRAY LIST FOR THE USERS
        while (file_in.hasNextLine()) {
            boolean isWorker = false;
            String current_line = file_in.nextLine();
            String[] line_split = current_line.split(",");
            if (line_split[2].equals("1")) {
                isWorker = true;
            }
            //Load the data To the List
            employees.add(new Employee(line_split[0], Integer.parseInt(line_split[1]), isWorker));
        }
        ArrayList<Employee> copyEmployeesList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        String userID = null;
        
        //loop 4 times then create output.txt
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            
            // This is where I'm trying to loop through the object to look for a match
            for(int b = 0; b < employees.size(); b++) {
                employees.get(userID);
            }
                   
            // User inputs userID and checks to see if theres a match
            System.out.println("Enter employee ID of an employee?");
            userID = in.nextLine();
            for (Employee employee : employees){
                if (employee.getUserID().equalsIgnoreCase(userID)) {
                    copyEmployeesList1.add(employee);
                    //System.out.println(employee);
                    break;
                 } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect value, please try again");
                    System.out.println("Enter employee ID of an employee?");
                    userID = in.nextLine();
                    break;
                   } 
            } 
          
            // User inputs user salary and checks if it matches the previous userID's lines salary.
            System.out.println("Enter salary of the employee");
            String userSalary = in.nextLine();
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(userSalary);
                if(userInput == copyEmployeesList1.get(0).getUserSalary()) {
                    
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect value, please try again");
                    System.out.println("Enter salary of the employee");
                }
            
            // Redundant input my professor requires, but input a 1 or a 2
            System.out.println("Is this in a manager or worker? (Enter 1 for worker 2 for manager)");
            String userType = in.nextLine();
            boolean choice;
            choice = userType.equals("1");
            employees.add(new Employee(userID, Integer.parseInt(userSalary), choice));
        }
    
            //compile salaries
            for(Employee emp:employees) {
                ManagerEmployee.calculate(emp);
                WorkerEmployee.calculate(emp);
            }
            employees.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`employees` is an arraylist of `Employee`, you can only use .get to get by a specific index. You will need to use something like javas stream filter or a different method like in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-filter-collection-by-list).

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeesWithASpecificID = users.stream()
        .filter(employee -> employee.getUserID() == userID)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```